# Azure Active Directory Application vs Azure Batch Service for Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I am following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-dot-net
to develop `C#` `.NET` based console application for `ETL` solution using `Azure Data Factory`.

It covers `Azure Active Directory Application` and `Azure Batch Service` is not mentioned. But this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity covers `Azure Batch Service`

Both `Azure Active Directory` and `Azure Batch Service` are completely new to me.
I need to know whether I need both for my `ETL` Solution or not

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish regarding your ETL solution? Azure active directory and azure batch service are two unrelated, completely different offerings

Comment: @PeterBons ETL pipleline to extract data from sql server to warehouse database in Azure SQL Database and then transform and load into another Reporting Database on same Azure Server

Comment: Unless you need transformations that are not built-in you won't need to use azure batch. Azure active directory is for authorization/authentication, possibly to your database but every azure subscription has one already.

Comment: You don't have to code the process, you could use the designer as well as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal

Comment: @PeterBons thanks. we code everything in our software house